# Why does this function use 100% cpu only if call it by onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I update the page I call the function setCity() but taking the data from the sessionStorage.

```
setCity(sessionData.city_id, sessionData.product_id);
```

But I also have a button that allows you to change cities

```
$(document).on("click", "#setCity", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $addApp.show(); //Show form
  document.getElementById("addApp").reset(); //Reset form
  const id = $(this).data("id");
  const city = $(this).data("city");
  const city_id = $(this).data("cityid");
  const product_id = $(this).data("product_id");
  const tec = $(this).data("tec");
  const tec_id = $(this).data("tecid");
  const campaign_id = $(this).data("campaign_id");

  sessionStorage.setItem(
    "working_city",
    JSON.stringify({
      city: city,
      id: id,
      city_id: city_id,
      product_id: product_id,
      tec: tec,
      tec_id: tec_id,
      campaign_id: campaign_id
    })
  );
  // Fill form inputs
  $("#cityInfo").show();
  $city.val(city);
  $city_id.val(city_id);
  $product_id.val(product_id);
  $tec.val(tec);
  $tec_id.val(tec_id);
  $("#assignedCity").text(city);

  //get new data
  setCity(city_id, campaign_id);
});
```

I don't understand why but when I press the button the cpu would like to explode but if I update the page it executes the function without problems

There is the main function setCity();

```
function setCity(city_id, campaign_id) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "api/contacts/contacts.php",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      type: "getPBContact",
      data: { city_id: city_id, pb_campaign_id: campaign_id }
    })
  }).done(res => {
    console.log(res);
    var data = res.data;

    if (res.success) {
      data.forEach(e => {
        $address.val(e.address);
        $full_name.val(e.full_name);
        var tel = new libphonenumber.AsYouType("IT").input(e.tel);
        var cel = new libphonenumber.AsYouType("IT").input(e.cel);
        $telefono.val(tel);
        $cellulare.val(cel);
        $address_book_id.val(e.id);
        $city_id.val(city_id);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

#### Edit:

I believe I have found the problem and I assume it is in the query thats "**ORDER BY RAND()**":

```
SELECT * FROM ' . $this->tableName . ' ab 
            WHERE 
            ab.source = "PB" AND 
            ab.city_id = :city_id AND 
            pb_campaign_id = :pb_campaign_id AND 
            ab.id NOT IN (SELECT address_book_id FROM calls WHERE calls.address_book_id = ab.id AND calls.status_id IN ("C","NO") OR (calls.status_id IN ("NR","OC") AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,calls.updated_at,NOW()) < 30))
            ORDER BY RAND() <----- THIS!!!
            LIMIT 1';
```

There is a solution for "**ORDER BY RAND()**" but in big tables?

Comment: You are causing a lot of browser repaints for one. That is why jquery has been demoted in favour of other frameworks due to poor use of constant re-rendering. That would hit performance certainly but it might not be the cause of it. Perhaps comment out each line one by one and retest until you can see the offending item.

Comment: @SteveTomlin ok im sure the problem is the mysql query. It had a "ORDER BY RAND()" and is slowly because it's a big table

Comment: What have you tried to check which part is responsible? Is this a browser-side problem, or a server-side problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase was a server-side problem. I figured out the problem was the query (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64266163/problems-with-order-by-rand-and-big-tables)