# Problems with ORDER BY RAND() and big tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb

Hello I asked a question this morning, and I realized that the problem was not where I was looking ([here the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64259451/why-does-this-function-use-100-cpu-only-if-call-it-by-onclick-event))

I have this query to randomly generate registries from an address book.

```
SELECT * FROM address_book ab 
            WHERE 
            ab.source = "PB" AND 
            ab.city_id = :city_id AND 
            pb_campaign_id = :pb_campaign_id AND 
            ab.id NOT IN (SELECT address_book_id FROM calls WHERE calls.address_book_id = ab.id AND calls.status_id IN ("C","NO") OR (calls.status_id IN ("NR","OC") AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,calls.updated_at,NOW()) < 30))
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1';
```

but I noticed that "order by rand ()" take more than 50s and use up to 25-50% CPU with large tables (100k +) so i looked for solutions here but i didn't find anything that worked.
note: **ids are not self-incrementing, there may be gaps**

Any idea?

Comment: Please define *doesn't work very well*

Comment: @GMB edited, sorry.

Comment: Do you need an SQL only solution, or can another language be used to help with this?

Comment: @TomRevell SQL is better but (if possible) php solutions are valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM address_book ab 
WHERE ab.source = 'PB' AND 
      ab.city_id = :city_id AND 
      pb_campaign_id = :pb_campaign_id AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM calls c
                  WHERE c.address_book_id = ab.id AND
                        ( c.status_id IN ('C', 'NO') OR
                         (c.status_id IN ('NR', 'OC') AND c.updated < now() - interval 30 minute)
                        ) 
                )

ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that this changes the logic in the correlated subquery so `c.address_book_id = ab.id` always applies.  I suspect that is the issue with performance.

Then, create indexes on:

- `address_book(source, city_id, campaign_id, id)`
- `calls(address_book_id, status_id, updated)`

I am guessing that this will be sufficient to improve performance.  If there happen to be a zillion rows that match the conditions, then the `order by rand()` might be an issue.

Comment: Thanks! i figured out problem was  "calls.address_book_id = ab.id"

Answer (score 0):

1. I will never suggest for sub query in huge DB its take long execution time.
2. Use proper indexing and if its require use inner join(never use left join)
3. if possible use your business logic in php script because maybe your db will more large and take too much time for execute such query.
4. if you want only one data in large db don't use `rand()` function, take any rand number (1 to db rows count) and use limit `limit skip,number` ex.
   `limit 2,1` its give row 3 only
   Hope its useful.